Missing dependencies and command failed with exit code 1:.....gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug
I am facing this horrible issue while building my mobile app using Cordova.
I am testing the output to get an apk file to test on mobile phone. However I am stack on an error as shown on the picture attached.
Environmental variables have been set:
JAVA_HOME,ANDROID_HOME,ANDROID_SDK_HOME,and the following to PATH:

Build Tools
Platform-tools
Emulator
Gradle/bin

I tried cleaning using cordova clean and changing various variables in dependencies section and Kotlin version in build.gradle.
Am using Gradle 8, Kotlin 1.9.22 but the version in build.gradle is 1.8.0.
I thought changing these could solve the issue.
